# npm start isn't working in new React apps?

Tags: npm

I've removed and reinstalled NPM and Node, still no fix. Here's the error code after I create-react-app and input npm start.

````
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/carriepresley/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/carriepresley/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent```
````

Comment: I think there is no `package.json` file where you run `npm install`. Ensure that there is `package.json` is located or not.

Answer (score 2):

Use `cd` to the directory where `package.json` is located and then run the `npm start` command. This will work.